# Strange results performing box blur on Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, signal-processing, convolution

I'm using Numpy to perform an operation on an array quickly. Specifically, I'd like every position in the array's value to be set to the average of all of its immediate neighbors, effectively making values "spread" and disperse. The intended application of this is actually to simulate the behavior of smells in a video game; the value in the array represents the strength of the smell of a particular object, and the strength is set to 100 at the position of the object every turn.

I know there are packages that exist for this purpose, but I'd really rather not introduce any more massive dependencies than I have to; Numpy is kinda pushing it as it is!

Unfortunately, my code doesn't seem to work. The values "spread" perfectly; unfortunately, instead of "dispersing", they actually seem to *accumulate*, each value growing larger until it overflows.

Here's the code:

```
#Step 1: Set every object's scent value to its scentstrength at its position, simulating objects emitting scent
#(this also initializes the arrays if they haven't been yet as a side effect since scentmap is a defaultdict)
#Walls don't have smell, which is good 'cos there's a lot of em
scentsimulatedobjects=(theobj for theobj in self.objs if not isinstance(theobj,gameobjs.Wall))
for theobj in scentsimulatedobjects:
    thearray=scentmap[theobj]
    thearray[tuple(theobj.pos)]=theobj.scentstrength

#Step 2: Make the scents spread. This is done the same way as a simple "blur" effect in image processing;
#we just make every square's scent value the average of all of its neighbors. This is done by convolving the
#array with a blur convolution filter. I'm totally pretending I actually understand this stuff, I really don't.
spreadfactor=0.95
blur=numpy.array([spreadfactor, 1, spreadfactor])

for theobj, thearray in scentmap.items():
    for idx, therow in enumerate(thearray):
        thearray[idx] = numpy.convolve(therow, blur, "same")

    for idx in range(self.size):
        thearray[:, idx] = numpy.convolve(thearray[:, idx], blur, "same")

#Step 3: Scale the entire matrix by a decay factor, representing scents losing strength over time once their
#source #leaves
decayfactor=0.5
for theobj, thearray in self.scentmap.items():
    thearray*=decayfactor
    for x, therow in enumerate(thearray):
        for y, scentstrength in enumerate(therow):
            if scentstrength < 1:
                thearray[x,y]=0
```

How do I fix this?

Here's a pastebin of the algorithm isolated from context, so you can hack on it without downloading the entire project this is part of:
http://pastebin.com/gr2E6VWP

Comment: Could you give a complete example with some test data?

Comment: You need to divide your kernel (`blur`) by its sum, such that it sums to 1

Comment: @ali_m I'm not sure I understand - I should divide every number in the kernel by... eight? I literally just learned all this today via Google, I have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: @ali_m Oh, I get it, it's like normalizing a vector. It looks like it works now. Thanks!